# How can I do a rails migration and rails seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis, database-migration, seed

I would like to do a rails migration and a rails seed with this postgresql query. How can I do that ?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS grid_light;
  CREATE TABLE grid_light AS
  SELECT DISTINCT g.ogc_fid AS id, g.geog4326 AS geog
  FROM grid g, tracks t
  WHERE t.path_buff_geog && g.geog4326 AND ST_Intersects(t.path_buff_geog, g.geog4326);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be create a rake task ( exp: create **grids.rake** in your lib/task )

```rb
namespace :grids do
  desc 'explain your rake here'
  task create_grid: :environment do
    drop_sql_cmd = <<-SQL
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS grid_light;
    SQL

    create_sql_cmd = <<-SQL
      CREATE TABLE grid_light AS
      SELECT DISTINCT g.ogc_fid AS id, g.geog4326 AS geog
      FROM grid g, tracks t
      WHERE t.path_buff_geog && g.geog4326 AND ST_Intersects(t.path_buff_geog, g.geog4326);
    SQL
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(drop_sql_cmd)
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(create_sql_cmd)
    end
  end
end
```

and if call rake as

```
bundle exec rake grids:create_grid
```